# Retrieve properties for a feature in MVT from JSONB column?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, vector-tiles

**TL;DR** Check the last **UPDATE** section.

We store all of our geometries in a single hybrid PostGIS table and corresponding properties in a single JSONB column. Properties can be anything and differ for each type of "feature". What I am looking for is a way to retrieve properties in ST_AsMVT query and turn them into... well... properties of the resulting feature.

ST_AsMVT definitely doesn't recognize them out of the box.

There is the following paragraph in [ST_AsMVT](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html) doc:

> The Mapbox Vector Tile format **can store features with varying sets of attributes**. To use this capability **supply a JSONB column** in the row data containing Json objects one level deep. The keys and values in the JSONB values will be encoded as feature attributes.

Which sounds kind of exactly what I'm trying to achieve, but it doesn't work. And it is not exactly clear if it is indeed about same usage scenario. And there are no examples.

Does anyone know if what I described is possible? Or what that paragraph from ST_AsMVT doc actually means?

**UPDATE:**

I went to find an exact change in PostGIS itself that [added this functionality](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3749?cversion=0&cnum_hist=3), and they have this example in their internal tests:

```sql
SELECT 
  'TA9', 
  encode(
    ST_AsMVT('test', 4096, 'geom', q), 
    'base64'
  ) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      '{"c1":1,"c2":"abcd"}' :: jsonb, 
      ST_AsMVTGeom(
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(25 17)'), 
        ST_MakeBox2D(
          ST_Point(0, 0), 
          ST_Point(4096, 4096)
        ), 
        4096, 
        0, 
        false
      ) AS geom
  ) AS q;
```

Notice `'{"c1":1,"c2":"abcd"}' :: jsonb` line - when requested like this it indeed ends up spread as properties on resulting feature in MVT response! But when the name of an actual JSONB column is supplied instead of hardcoded JSON string, it fails to recognize it.

**UPDATE:**

Turns out while properties were placed in JSONB column, they were put there in a stringified form for some reason. Once I converted them all to a proper JSON, everything started to work as I thought it should!